# How to access json object appended as form data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am passing object of arrays  from frontend to backend(react to node)  i am using the new FormData and append the "user" obj in the form  and then i pass formdata object to my api.

[user object in console log view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRCCu.png)

As shown in the pic this is my obj of arrays object.

**This is my react js Code** i am passing this user object to backend.

```
const formData = new FormData()
 formData.append("user", user)
  axios.post('http://localhost:5000/AddEmployee', 
    formData
        )
```

**Below code is Node js Code**

console.log(typeof req.body.user)

It is showing us the string in console log view.

And In debugger mode the user object is showing in this form.
'[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]'

How can i access this object.

And i want to access this object in the below mentioned form.

let primary = req.body.user[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRCCu.png)].primaryContact;

Answer (score 0):

1. "How can i access this object."

Convert the array to a json string so you can see what's in it:

`console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body.user))`

2. "And i want to access this object in the below mentioned form."

In order to answer this question, we need to see what the structure of user is. Hopefully my first answer should help with that! If you need more help, post the output to my first answer.

Comment: "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
Json Stringify output

Comment: Thanks I have resovled this issue from front end i passed the object as json stringify and from backend i parsed this object.